# How to redirect url in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have mvc3 application here my problem is on same page i.e on `Index.cshtml`
i have two partial view `controlpartial.cshtml` and `webgridpartial.cshtml`

now when i'm inserting data into database it works fine and page gets redirect to `Index.cshtml` and URL also gets clear.

But at the time of edit when i clicked on edit button and update all values and submit that values it is updated perfectly in database but page is not able to redirect again to `Index.cshtml` nor my URL gets cleared :(

Because of that I'm not able to edit any values once i done edit need to manually reset Index URL.

Any guesses?

Index.cshtml

```
@model Mapping.Models.SecurityIdentifierMappingViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

### Index

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


@*Partial control for all controls*@

<div id="main">
<div style="float:left;width:30%">
@Html.Partial("_ControlsPartial",Model)
</div>


<div style="margin-left:600px;margin-top:-20px">
@Html.Partial("_WebGridPartial",Model.MappingWebGridList)
</div>

</div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
  mydataEntities dbContext = new mydataEntities();
    DataRepository objRepository = new DataRepository();
//GET

public ActionResult Index(string userAction="Create",int id = 0 )
{
    var mappingobj = new SecurityIdentifierMappingViewModel();
    mappingobj.MappingWebGridList = dbContext.SecurityIdentifierMappings.ToList();

    if (id!=null && id > 0)
    {

        mappingobj.MappingControls = dbContext.SecurityIdentifierMappings.Find(id);
        if (userAction == "Delete")
        {
            dbContext.SecurityIdentifierMappings.Remove(mappingobj.MappingControls);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mappingobj.MappingControls = new SecurityIdentifierMapping();
        mappingobj.MappingControls.PricingSecurityID = 0;
        mappingobj.MappingControls.CUSIP = "";
    }
    mappingobj.PricingSecurities = objRepository.GetPricingSecurityID();
    mappingobj.CUSIPs = objRepository.GetCUSIP();

    return View(mappingobj);
}


//POST

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SecurityIdentifierMappingViewModel objModel)
{
      //edit code
     if (objModel.MappingControls.Id > 0)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                dbContext.Entry(objModel.MappingControls).State = EntityState.Modified;
                try
                {
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

        }

        //insert code
        else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                dbContext.SecurityIdentifierMappings.Add(objModel.MappingControls);
                try
                {
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

        }

        objModel.MappingWebGridList = dbContext.SecurityIdentifierMappings.ToList();
        objModel.PricingSecurities = objRepository.GetPricingSecurityID();
        objModel.CUSIPs = objRepository.GetCUSIP();
        objModel.MappingControls = new SecurityIdentifierMapping();

        return View(objModel);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommend instead of

```
return View(objModel);
```

to do

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new {Id = null});
```

This is called Post-Redirect-Get model (PRG).

If you wish to keep objModel. Place it in TempData and on Index(Get), to check TempData if the object is there. To use that instead of loading a new one.

Comment: I do not see any problems currently. Suggest that you use breakpoints and track the path of your code. You could be hitting another Action.

Comment: Nope all going good into break point but after editing or deleting i'm not able to redirect to index as you can ssee into above image url is home/index/ and id :(

Comment: Ahh, i see now. I have ammended my answer. See how I am clearing the Id? Edit: It should be null or it could be empty string `""`

Answer (score 1):

You would need a RedirectToAction somewhere in your code to take it back to the original index.

Plus, you're doing it a little bit wrong. The whole point of MVC is that your actions would (mostly) correspond to CRUD. Ergo, you would have an Edit action. You would also have Create and Delete. Obviously, you can have more or less or even different actions, but the whole point of MVC is to make it simpler, not harder.

Routing and actions are there for a reason, to avoid writing monolithic code. I would strongly suggest you to take a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Even though it would appear that you know the basics of ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC is a little bit different beast :)

Comment: hi..i have already redirected to `Index` look at `edit code` and `insert code` in `HomeController.cs`

Comment: Right, it's still way off in my opinion. It keeps itself monolithic, and since you're using "Useractions" anyway, I strongly suggest using Edit actions separately from Index.